# MySQLWorkbench - error message - Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte Oxe4 in position 9: ordinal not in range (128)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I was trying to use table data import wizard to import a csv file that uses utf-8 character set, and then the following error message shows up.

[image: error message]

> MySQLWorkbench - error message - Unhandled exception: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte Oxe4 in position 9: ordinal not in range (128)

I have tried to set the schema's character set to utf-8/utfmb4, but it didn't work. The csv file is converted from Excel, and all its cells have been set to text form. I have to use utf-8 for the needed table for future use. How can I import this csv file? Do I need to change the server and the database's encoding language? If so, how can I do this on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this exact issue by opening up MySQLWorkbench using terminal instead of Finder:

```
$ open /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app
```

This solution was found to solve a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71099489/mysql-workbench-table-export-unicodeencodeerror

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have `ä` in your data.  That is hex `E4` in `CHARACTER SET latin1`.

If you are expecting `ä`, then you need to declare something "latin1", not Ascii'.

It is also possible that `E4` is part of a UTF-8 character.  Let's see some more data to help you.